# Theory and mathematical background of active contour and segmentation models

Tags: image-segmentation, calculus

I am looking for reference books/online material for self-learning the mathematical background in active contours and segmentation models (e.g., snakes, level set, geodesic). Can someone help me with hints?

Comment: (1) Any multivariable Calculus textbook followed by (2) a good elementary introduction to differential geometry.

Comment: thanks @whuber, can you suggest something more specific? that would help me a lot.

Comment: It depends on your mathematical background.  There are thousands of Calculus texts and many dozens of good differential geometry texts.  Some of the latter can be read only by PhD mathematicians and others are accessible to college freshman, so you will need to look wherever in that spectrum suits you.

Comment: there is an introduction here https://www.coursera.org/learn/image-processing#modules modules 5 & 6. but the full mathematics is graduate level

Comment: thanks, @seanv507. Actually, I started this journey after taking that course in Coursera and having implemented the approaches. I wanted to get a better understanding of the derivation of the algorithms.

Comment: I think you should rather ask on the signal processing site.